# Range of $n(A \Delta B)$ in sets A and B

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was trying to solve this question-

"If 2 sets A and B are such that n(A) = 15 and n(B) = 25, find the no. of elements in the range of $n(A \Delta B)$.Now, this is what I did-

For $n(A\Delta B)$ to be maximum, $n(A \cap B)$ should be minimum, i.e.$0$.

Thus, $n(A\Delta B)= n(A\cup B) - n(A\cap B)$ = $n(A) + n(B) - 0$ = $25+15=40$

For the minimum value of $n(A \Delta B)$, $A \subset B$, i.e. $n(A \cap B) = n(A) =15$. Also, for minimum value of the symmetric difference, $A\subset B$ means that $n(A \cup B) = n(B) = 25$.

Thus, minimum value is $n(A\Delta B)= n(A\cup B) - n(A\cap B)$ = $25-15=10$

Thus, the range should be max. value - min. value = $40 -10 =30$.
But the answer is given as 16. How?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are counting the number of different values that can be taken on by $n(A\Delta B)$. The amount of overlap between $A$ and $B$ can be any of $0$ to $15$, and each gives a different value for $n(A\Delta B)$. For example, an overlap of $1$ gives $n(A\Delta B)=38$, and overlap of $2$ gives $n(A\Delta B)=36$, and so on. So $n(A\Delta B)$ can take on any one of $16$ different values.

Comment: what do mean by overlap here? I don't seem to get your point. Can you please explain it a bit furthur?

Comment: I was using "the amount of overlap between $A$ and $B$" as an informal term for $n(A\cap B)$.  Your calculations for the max and min were right, but if $n(A\cap B)$ increases by $1$, the cardinality of the symmetric difference decreases by $2$, giving $16$ distinct values for the possible cardinality of the symmetric difference.

Comment: OP, you are right about the max and min values, but note that not every value in between them is attained.

Comment: ok, but how does that relate to the range?Isn't the range supposed to be the set {10,11,12,.......40}?, and hence no. of elements in it 30??  am really confused, as 30 is an option ( its a multiple choice question)

Comment: The range is the set $\{10,12,14,\dots,40\}$.

Comment: How?? why only even numbers?? now I am more comfused..hehe

Comment: You know what happens if $n(A\cap B)=0$. Suppose now that $n(A\cap B)=1$. Then $n(A\Delta B)=n(A)+n(B)-2n(A\cap B)=38$. You are using the wrong formula for $n(A\Delta B)$. The post uses the formula for $n(A\cup B)$. But I was really not thinking in terms of formulas, just seeing what happens if we increase $n(A\cap B)$ (the amount of overlap) by $1$.

Comment: oh yeah....i get it now..........$A \Delta B = (A \cup B) - (A\cap B)$....i forgot to include the latter term....sorry for being silly mate.....thanks

Comment: You are welcome. It is natural, after computing the ends, to assume everything in between is possible.